# Check if key exists in dictionary. If not, append it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large python dict created from json data and am creating a smaller dict from the large one. Some elements of the large dictionary have a key called 'details' and some elements don't. What I want to do is check if the key exists in each entry in the large dictionary and if not, append the key 'details' with the value 'No details available' to the new dictionary. I am putting some sample code below just as a demonstration. The LargeDict is much larger with many keys in my code, but I'm keeping it simple for clarity.

```
LargeDict = {'results':
[{'name':'john','age':'23','datestart':'12/07/08','department':'Finance','details':'Good Employee'},
 {'name':'barry','age':'26','datestart':'25/08/10','department':'HR','details':'Also does payroll'},
 {'name':'sarah','age':'32','datestart':'13/05/05','department':'Sales','details':'Due for promotion'},
 {'name':'lisa','age':'21','datestart':'02/05/12','department':'Finance'}]}
```

This is how I am getting the data for the SmallDict:

```
SmallDict = {d['name']:{'department':d['department'],'details':d['details']} for d in LargeDict['results']}
```

I get a key error however when one of the large dict entries has no details. Am I right in saying I need to use the `DefaultDict` module or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `get(key, defaultVar)` method to supply a default value when the `'details'` key is missing:

```
SmallDict = {d['name']:{'department':d['department'],'details':d.get('details','No details available')} for d in LargeDict['results']}
```

Answer (score 13):

You don't need a `collections.defaultdict`.  You can use the `setdefault` method of dictionary objects.

```
d = {}
bar = d.setdefault('foo','bar') #returns 'bar'
print bar # bar
print d  #{'foo': 'bar'}
```

As others have noted, if you don't want to add the key to the dictionary, you can use the `get` method.

here's an old [reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html) that I often find myself looking at.

Comment: +1 (From the docs) dict.setdefault(): "If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None."

Comment: Yes. Use this.  defaultdict is an evil creature for the unwary.

Comment: FWIW, I think `defaultdict` is great.  Mainly, I don't think it's worth converting a regular `dict` to a `defaultdict` if you've gotten it from another source.  The "evils" of `defaultdict` can be circumvented simply by setting the `default_factory` attribute to `None` (which will make it behave like a regular dict once again).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `collections.defaultdict` if you want to create an entry in your `dict` automatically. However, if you don't, and just want "Not available" (or whatever), then you can just assign to the `dict` as `d[key] = v` and use `d.get(k, 'Not available')` for a default value